# Angular http.get + WebApi = Cors failure

Tags: angularjs, cors, asp.net-web-api2

on server side I have a C# web api including a controller attributed like this on class level:

```js
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:51664,http://localhost,...", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

I can make ajax calls, e.g. form localhost just fine.

Now I am starting with AngularJS and the http.get-method fails with the following message:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/DividendsManager.Web.Api/api/securities/GetSecurities?yearsDividendsDontDecrease=40. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.*

This is my AngularJS code:

```js
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {

            var onSuccess = function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.data = data;
            };

            var onError = function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.error = status;
            }

            var promise = $http.get("http://localhost:8081/DividendsManager.Web.Api/api/securities/GetSecurities?yearsDividendsDontDecrease=40");

            promise.success(onSuccess);
            promise.error(onError);
        });
</script>
```

In Fiddler, I can see, that the header of the AngularJS-HTTP-Get request has an "Origin: null" entry, which seems to be related to the problem. I think, if instead "null" the value would be "http://localhost", it should work.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to implement CORS server side as the ports are different. That constitutes a different origin as far as browsers are concerned

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because in your `[EnableCors]` attribute, you need to change `headers: "", methods: ""` to `headers: "*", methods: "*"`?

Also, you should not include a forward slash at the end of the `origins` url (if you did).

Comment: Hi kimbaudi,

thanks for anwer. In the attribute, I did "*", not "". Sorry for typo error. Also I did not use forward slash at the end (http://localhost, not http://localhost/). As said, other ajax calls work fine. It just seems to be AngularJS problem.

Comment: Could you post the HTTP header response? Are you getting something like `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS` `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`?  You may have to set the allowed HTTP Methods in your ApiController: `public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }`

Comment: Hi kimbuaid,

thanks for your help. But now I am aware of my own mistake and it works - until next time ;)

See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in our project and we tried so many options as per the suggestions from various web sites. But the thing that worked/working in our case is writing custom CORS provider as mentioned [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#cors-policy-providers).

Comment: Hi sam,
I think the problem is on the client side, because the origin attribute in the html header is null. The server works correct by denying this. If I use other ajax technologies than AngularJS, it works as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Upppps!

When running in the fresh air today I suddenly was aware why Origin was null. It was, because I was not calling the web site in IIS, but instead I opened the file directly in the file system. For sure, there was no valid URL when doing so, and the Origin was null for the web server.